# Is rigid body mechanics included in classical mechanics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

Can rigid body mechanics be derived from Newtonian, Lagrangian or any other formulation of classical mechanics? Or do we need some extra axioms or laws?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Can rigid body mechanics be derived from Newtonian, Lagrangian or any other formulation of classical mechanics? Or do we need some extra axioms or laws?***

PiKindOfGuy is correct. Classical mechanics is the basis of rigid body mechanics and Newton’s laws apply.

I would simply add that you do need to learn some additional concepts to facilitate the evaluation of the dynamic and static behavior of rigid bodies.  However, I don’t believe these additional concepts have the status of additional “axioms” or “laws”.

For example, in statics you need to learn about resolving forces; moments (couples); systems of forces; centroids of masses, areas, lengths and volumes; moment of inertia and the parallel axis theorem; radius of gyration, etc., to name a few. But these all basically boil down to applications of classical mechanics.

If the body is not rigid (i.e., it is deformable), you need to add mechanics of materials concepts as well (Hooke’s Law, axial and torsional stress/strain, analysis of beams and columns, etc.)

Hope this helps.